# In Python, scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr and lsqr are giving incorrect answers. How do I fix this issue?

Tags: python

I have to solve a least squares problem with a damping term:
min ||Ax-b||_2^2  + lambda^2 ||x||_2^2

Note that A is a sparse matrix. I want to use either lsqr or lsmr in Python to solve this. I tried this problem in MATLAB using lsmr and got the correct answer. However when I try this in Python, the result is different than the MATLAB answer and is incorrect. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

```
import scipy.io
import scipy.sparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.sparse.linalg import cg

#Load mat files from Finnish Inverse Problems society webpage (carved cheese dataset)
data = scipy.io.loadmat('DataFull_512x15.mat')

A = data['A']
m = data['m']

b = m.flatten()

lam=10

A_T = A.transpose()

N = int(math.sqrt(np.shape(A)[1]))

x_a=scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr(A,b, damp=lam**2)[0]
x_a = x_a.reshape((N,N))


x=scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr(A, b, damp=lam**2)[0]
x = x.reshape((N,N))


#Plot using LSMR
plt.imshow(x_a,cmap = 'gray', interpolation='nearest')

#Plot using LSQR
plt.imshow(x,cmap = 'gray', interpolation='nearest')


###############################################################################


#Conjugate gradient method
left=scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator((A.shape[1],A.shape[1]),lambda x: A_T@(A@x)+(lam**2)*x)
soln = cg(left,A_T@b,  tol=1e-08)


soln = soln[0].reshape((512,512))

plt.imshow(soln,cmap = 'gray', interpolation='nearest')
```

The code I wrote is shown above. I try to use LSQR, LSMR, and CG and get the same incorrect results for all 3 methods. The data is the carved cheese data set from the Finnish Inverse Problems society webpage for the x-ray reconstruction problem.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you show your Python code? Chances are that the scipy implementation is correct and something about how its being used in your particular case is causing the problem.

Comment: I just edited it to add my code!